# Logging an unknown exception in Python

Tags: python, exception

I am getting an exception on an HTTP GET request (http.client.HTTPConnection.getresponse), but so far have been unable to determine the nature of the exception (my Python is fairly rudimentary). The code looks like this:

```
try:
    r = conn.getresponse()
except Exception as x:
    logger.error('Error getting data:' + str(x))
```

This just results in logs looking like `Error getting data:''`. I could trap all the different types of exception that HTTPConnection.getresponse can raise, but that seems ridiculous given there are so many possible exception types and I'm just trying to debug how the connection is failing. Is there a way to inspect the exception object?

Comment: Show it’s `type(x)` or for a full trace, pass `exc_info=True` into that log statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost certainly want to use `logger.exception` if you're using Python's standard library logger which adds more info about the exception (including a call stack).

From the docs:

> `Logger.exception()` creates a log message similar to `Logger.error()`. The difference is that `Logger.exception()` dumps a stack trace along with it. Call this method only from an exception handler.

If you want to specifically format the type of the exception in your log message, do:

```
try:
    r = conn.getresponse()
except Exception as e:
    logger.error('%s: %s', type(e), e)
```